# X11 include files not installed with Xquartz on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, include, x11, osx-mavericks

I have a brand new Mac Book Pro and am trying to get my dev environment set up. I have installed Xcode 5.0.2, command line tools (late october command line tools for Mavericks) and finally XQuartz 2.7.5. Everything went fine except than there X11 includes are nowhere to be found. /usr/X11 only contains lib, libexec and bin directories.

On my former laptop, I updated to Mavericks, reinstalled new Xcode, command line tools and finally Xquartz as well and it all worked out. I suppose it because I had old includes preinstalled but I can't be sure.

any hint? Is there a XQuartz-dev package?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How did you install XQuartz?

Comment: Have you looked in `/opt`?

Comment: XQuartz installed from standard package on website [link]http://xquartz-dl.macosforge.org/SL/XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg[/link]